# Calabash-Android seems to perform everything twice

Tags: android, ruby, automated-tests, robotium, calabash-android

I'm posting this on here even though I had posted this as an issue on the calabash github as well, since it's been 3 weeks and I haven't heard anything from support. Please let me know if you see something I'm doing wrong, or if you've experienced the same issue. Currently I'm running Calabash-Android v 0.5.8 on ruby 1.9.3. I have tested this in older versions of Calabash-Android and still have the same issue.

I've been trying to research into improving the performance of the tests I have setup, and one issue i've found from calabash from the start is that the app seems to duplicate calls in the **app_life_cycle_hooks.rb** file. Whenever my tests run, a test server is spawned and the app starts up, then another is spawned and they app restarts. On fail, two screenshots are taken instead of just one. Running a test in "-v" mode shows these calls twice (noted by asterisks below) :

```
2015-03-24 12:00:38 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-03-24 12:00:38 - Trying to find launchable activity
2015-03-24 12:00:38 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-03-24 12:00:38 - Found launchable activity 'com.XXXX.YYYY.MainActivity'
2015-03-24 12:00:38 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
****2015-03-24 12:00:38 - Starting test server using:
2015-03-24 12:00:38 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s a35e9829 shell am instrument -e target_package com.XXXX.YYYY -e main_activity com.XXXX.YYYY.MainActivity -e test_server_port 7102 -e class sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend com.XXXX.YYYY.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner
2015-03-24 12:00:38 - Checking if instrumentation backend is ready
2015-03-24 12:00:38 - Is app running? true
2015-03-24 12:00:38 - Instrumentation backend not yet ready
2015-03-24 12:00:41 - Checking if instrumentation backend is ready
2015-03-24 12:00:41 - Is app running? true
2015-03-24 12:00:41 - Instrumentation backend is ready!
2015-03-24 12:00:41 - Checking client-server version match...
2015-03-24 12:00:41 - Action: version - Params: 
2015-03-24 12:00:42 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"0.5.8","success":true}'
2015-03-24 12:00:42 - Client and server versions match (client: 0.5.8, server: 0.5.8). Proceeding...
2015-03-24 12:00:42 - connected_devices: ["a35e9829"]
2015-03-24 12:00:42 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s a35e9829 forward tcp:34779 tcp:7102
2015-03-24 12:00:42 - 
2015-03-24 12:00:42 - Action: set_activity_orientation - Params: portrait
2015-03-24 12:00:43 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"","success":true}'
2015-03-24 12:00:43 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-03-24 12:00:43 - Trying to find launchable activity
2015-03-24 12:00:43 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-03-24 12:00:43 - Found launchable activity 'com.XXXX.YYYY.MainActivity'
2015-03-24 12:00:43 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
**2015-03-24 12:00:43 - Starting test server using:
2015-03-24 12:00:43 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s a35e9829 shell am instrument -e target_package com.XXXX.YYYY -e main_activity com.XXXX.YYYY.MainActivity -e test_server_port 7102 -e class sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend com.XXXX.YYYY.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner
2015-03-24 12:00:44 - Checking if instrumentation backend is ready
2015-03-24 12:00:44 - Is app running? true
2015-03-24 12:00:44 - Instrumentation backend not yet ready
```

Below you will find the **app_life_cycle_hooks** file I'm currently using, with no possibility for duplicate calls or whatnot, it was created via **calabash-android gen**. I added a helper for screen, which will rotate the android device to proper orientation on test start, rather than at whatever orientation it is currently at, but this should not affect the spawning multiple servers as the code can be ripped out and the same results still show. Something under the hood seems to be accessing my *apps_life_cycle_hooks** file multiple times.

```
#require 'calabash-android/management/adb'
require 'calabash-android/operations'
require_relative '../helpers/screen'

Before do |scenario|
  if (scenario.source_tag_names.include?('@reset'))
    clear_app_data
  end
  start_test_server_in_background
  $screen = Screen.new
  $screen.rotate_to_proper_position()
end

After do |scenario|
    if scenario.failed?
        print "Test failed: #{scenario.name}\n"
       if scenario.exception.message =="HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected" || scenario.exception.message =="EOFError"
         puts "*********HTTP error!! attempting to restart test server!*************"
         reinstall_test_server
         start_test_server_in_background
       end
       if scenario.failed?
           screenshot_embed
       end
    end
    shutdown_test_server
end
```

**EDIT: adding screen file as well

```
require 'calabash-android/operations'

class Screen
    include Calabash::Android::Operations
    def size
        return @size
    end
    def device
        return @device
    end
    def get_screen_size()
        window = query('*')[0]["class"]
        dm = query(window,:getResources,:getDisplayMetrics)[0]
        x = (dm["widthPixels"]/dm["xdpi"])**2
        y = (dm["heightPixels"]/dm["ydpi"])**2
        inches = Math.sqrt(x+y)
        @size= inches.round(1)
    end
    def check_device()
         screenSize = get_screen_size()
         if(screenSize >=6.5 )
            @device = "tablet"
         else
            @device = "phone"
         end

    end
    def rotate_to_proper_position
        device = check_device()
        if(device.eql? "phone")
             perform_action('set_activity_orientation', 'portrait')
        else
             perform_action('set_activity_orientation', 'landscape')
        end
    end
end
```

**EDIT 2** I am pasting a full log of one feature where the test server starts twice for no reason in particular

```
Using the android profile...
@areachart
Feature: AreaChart Visualization

  Background:                                            # features/areachart.feature:4
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - connected_devices: ["192.168.56.101:5555"]
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 forward tcp:34777 tcp:7102
4/2/15 10:59
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - Trying to find launchable activity
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - Found launchable activity 'com.XXXX.YYYY.MainActivity'
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - Starting test server using:
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell am instrument -e target_package com.XXXX.YYYY -e main_activity com.XXXX.YYYY.MainActivity -e test_server_port 7102 -e class sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend com.XXXX.YYYY.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - Checking if instrumentation backend is ready
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - Is app running? true
2015-04-02 10:59:25 - Instrumentation backend not yet ready
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Checking if instrumentation backend is ready
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Is app running? true
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Instrumentation backend is ready!
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Checking client-server version match...
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Action: version - Params: 
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"0.5.8","success":true}'
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Client and server versions match (client: 0.5.8, server: 0.5.8). Proceeding...
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Trying to find launchable activity
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Found launchable activity 'com.XXXX.YYYY.MainActivity'
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Found tools directory at '/Developer/android/sdk/build-tools/17.0.0'
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Starting test server using:
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell am instrument -e target_package com.XXXX.YYYY -e main_activity com.XXXX.YYYY.MainActivity -e test_server_port 7102 -e class sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend com.XXXX.YYYY.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Checking if instrumentation backend is ready
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Is app running? true
2015-04-02 10:59:28 - Instrumentation backend not yet ready
2015-04-02 10:59:31 - Checking if instrumentation backend is ready
2015-04-02 10:59:31 - Is app running? true
2015-04-02 10:59:31 - Instrumentation backend is ready!
2015-04-02 10:59:31 - Checking client-server version match...
2015-04-02 10:59:31 - Action: version - Params: 
2015-04-02 10:59:31 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"0.5.8","success":true}'
2015-04-02 10:59:31 - Client and server versions match (client: 0.5.8, server: 0.5.8). Proceeding...
2015-04-02 10:59:32 - connected_devices: ["192.168.56.101:5555"]
2015-04-02 10:59:32 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 forward tcp:34777 tcp:7102
4/2/15 10:59
    Given I am on the passcode screen                    # features/step_definitions/passcode_steps.rb:1
    And The passcode I enter for passcode screen is 1111 # features/step_definitions/passcode_steps.rb:18
2015-04-02 10:59:33 - connected_devices: ["192.168.56.101:5555"]
2015-04-02 10:59:33 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 forward tcp:34777 tcp:7102
4/2/15 10:59
2015-04-02 10:59:34 - connected_devices: ["192.168.56.101:5555"]
2015-04-02 10:59:34 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 forward tcp:34777 tcp:7102
4/2/15 10:59
    Then I am on the main screen                         # features/step_definitions/main_steps.rb:1

  @AreaNoLegend
  Scenario: No Legend                                              # features/areachart.feature:22
2015-04-02 10:59:35 - Action: clear_text - Params: 
2015-04-02 10:59:35 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"","success":true}'
touch failed! re-trying touching AreaChartSingle_NoLegend
    When I search for and tap dashboard "AreaChartSingle_NoLegend" # features/step_definitions/main_steps.rb:52
2015-04-02 10:59:36 - connected_devices: ["192.168.56.101:5555"]
2015-04-02 10:59:36 - "/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 forward tcp:34777 tcp:7102
4/2/15 10:59
    Then I am on the dashboard screen                              # features/step_definitions/dashboard_steps.rb:1
    Then the legend is not visible                                 # features/step_definitions/commonchart_steps.rb:411
2015-04-02 10:59:37 - It looks like your app is no longer running. 
It could be because of a crash or because your test script shut it down.
2015-04-02 10:59:37 - It looks like your app is no longer running. 
It could be because of a crash or because your test script shut it down.
2015-04-02 10:59:37 - Server not responding. Moving on.

1 scenario (1 passed)
6 steps (6 passed)
0m12.774s
```

Comment: What's in your `../helpers/screen`?

Comment: Added screen file to the bottom of my post

Comment: How are you running the tests that are duplicating the actions?  Any chance you could step through the tests in debug and see if it's your code being run through twice or if it's calabash on the back end doing things twice even though the code that's telling it to do things is only running once?

Comment: I recently created a config file for this test project yesterday, as I just started adding screens as well for iOS testing. It had seemed by doing that I ran some tests this morning and the project seemed to be working normally, until I hit a failing test. I'm not sure if maybe the test server doesn't properly close if a fail() condition is hit? I run my app now like this:

**calabash-android run <path_to_apk> -p android**

Comment: I just added a paste of the new log I receive when running a scenario using -v logging (which is as close as i've found to being able to debug) and as you can see there are still 2 test servers spawned. I am running this on a Genymotion virtual device running Nexus 10